# Hadoop File Read

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop  Distributed Cache Wordcount example in hadoop 2.2.0.
Copied file into hdfs filesystem to be used inside setup of mapper class.

```
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException 
{
      Path[] uris = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
      cacheData=new HashMap<String, String>();

      for(Path urifile: uris)
      {   
      try
      {

        BufferedReader readBuffer1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(urifile.toString()));
        String line;
        while ((line=readBuffer1.readLine())!=null)
        {      System.out.println("**************"+line);
               cacheData.put(line,line);
        }
        readBuffer1.close(); 
        }       
       catch (Exception e)
       {
                  System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
      }

}
```

Inside Driver Main class

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf,args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 3)
    {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = new Job(conf, "word_count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    Path outputpath=new Path(otherArgs[1]);
    outputpath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputpath,true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,outputpath);
    System.out.println("CachePath****************"+otherArgs[2]);
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(otherArgs[2]),job.getConfiguration());
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

But getting exception

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/user12/tmp/mapred/local/1408960542382/cache (No such file or directory)

So Cache functionality not working properly.
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

solved the issuse.
File location was wrongly given.
Now working fine.